# How to set global auth in karate?

Tags: dsl, karate

**Background**

I want to be able to set the auth token as a global variable for all my karate tests. I have tried the code below, however during execution, the runner hangs which leads me to believe the code isn't working

The code...

**karate-config.js**
[image]

The line of code `auth: call("get-user-token.feature")` being my attempt of setting the auth as a globalised variable

Answer (score 1):

The JS `call` method should be invoked as `karate.call` or `karate.callSingle` if you want to execute it only once

```
var config = {
    auth: karate.callSingle("get-user-token.feature")
};
```

karate builtins in JS are available as [karate Object](https://github.com/intuit/karate#the-karate-object)